# Showing text in selected row in NSTableView as white

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

In my application I have taken a table view and displaying some NSString objects within it. User can also edit any row within it.

When I do not change color of NSTextFieldCell in NSTableColumn in IB, it shows default display property of table view ie. when a row is selected, text of selected row starts appearing white,  but when I change it to some other color, say blue, then it starts appearing like this:

[image]

To resolve this problem I tried to set text color of cell in selected row as white in table delegate method: tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row:, but it caused another problem- text remained white when edited, thus it became difficult for user to identify text entered:

[image]

Can anyone suggest me some suitable solution to resolve it?

Thanks,

Miraaj

Answer (score 2):

Test [whether the cell is highlighted](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSCell_Class/Reference/NSCell.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCell/isHighlighted). If it is, set its text color to `[NSColor alternateSelectedControlTextColor]`. If not, set it to blue (or `[NSColor controlTextColor]` for the regular text color).